# how to add more textbox in angular2 using template driven form?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have create one template driven form in angular2. But, one field is add more dynamic. how to create dynamic field in angular2.

my html code like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of productModel.alert_email; let i = index">
                   <div class="col-md-11 m-b">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="productModel.alert_email[i]" name="alert_email[]" class="form-control" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" tabindex="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-1 m-b">
                        <a *ngIf="i==0" type="button" (click)="addMoreEmail($event)" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-plus more-alert-email"></i></a>
                        <a *ngIf="i>0" type="button" (click)="removeAlertEmail(i)" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o more-alert-email"></i></a>
                   </div>
             </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

my screen like:
[image]

I have allready create this add more. but, do not work properly.